# How can I output the Meteor Session key value pairs in a Handlebars template?

Tags: meteor

I want to output the Meteor Session key value pairs in a Meteor handlebars template.

http://docs.meteor.com/#session

I have tried returning Session and Session.keys from my Template.name.name js file and then #each in the handlebars to no avail.

I have tried the following to iterate over the Session keys and have tried return an object and it did not work.

I tried the following to iterate over the Session keys and returning a JSON list of data that looks like this.
{"myname":"my value","myname2":"myvalue2","myname3":"myvalue"}

```
_.each(Session.keys, function(element, index, list){

});
```

Comment: I think it might make more sense just to use an object within the Session so: Template.something.user = Session.get('user'); where user is an object. That way you won't get var name collisions. If the iteration works I would use it to set it all to an object then set that to a template var too.

Comment: That works for individual key/value pairs if you call them by key (aka name).  I want to iterate of the Meteor Session object and display the contents.  I have it working but I had to go at it from a different angle.  Also, experiencing weirdness with Session populated but I think view being displayed before hand.  Separate issue.

Comment: Aye, I wasn't sure what you were using it for that's all. Looks like the session package is using the .keys attribute also so its the nicest approach possible I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar question I asked that has a good solution by 7zark7

[Can I subscribe to Meteor Session for reactive template render updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760819/can-i-subscribe-to-meteor-session-for-reactive-template-render-updates)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an incredibly ugly solution but it works for now.  If someone finds a better solution please post your answer.  Obviously, you could return it as a JSON or some other kind of format.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getsessions', function() {
    var a = '<div class="span2"><b>name</b></div><div class="span2"><b>value</b></div><br />';
    _.each(Session.keys, function(element, index, list){
        a = a + '<div class="span2">' + index + '</div>' + 
        '<div class="span2">' + element + '</div><div class="span2"></div><br />';
    });
    return a;
  });
```

Then in the template I put this

```
{{#getsessions }}{{/getsessions}}
```

And it displays the Meteor Session contents in HTML.

There is a side effect I have to hunt down or post another SO on.  I populate a Meteor Session object on Meteor.startup BUT the above code does not display the contents every time or rather most of the time until the next view render.

S

Comment: Do a session.get for each key name and that should work to keep it fresh :).