# How to make reactive display from session with a template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have the following code in js

```
    var debug = {
                    "var1" : 1,
                    "var2" : 2
        };
setDisplayValues(debug);

function setDisplayValues(object){
    //Session.set("Display", object);
    if (Meteor.isClient){
        Session.set("Display", object);
    }
}
        Template.display.displayvar = function(){
            var obj = [], m = 1;

            for (var i in Session.get('Display')){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(i));
                if (i){
                    obj[m] = {name: i, value: Session.get('Display')[i]};
                }
                m++;
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
            return obj;
        };
```

And that in html:

```
<template name="display">
{{#each displayvar}}
    <p>{{this.name}} : {{this.value}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

The code works - it displays the values. But when they change it doesn't change accordingly, despite being saved in a session. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It worked for me after I wrapped the `Template.display.displayvar` in a `if (Meteor.isClient) { ...` — typing `Session.set('Display', { ... });` in the JavaScript console, the html did update.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760819/can-i-subscribe-to-meteor-session-for-reactive-template-render-updates

Comment: I always wrap them in `if (Meteor.isClient)` because otherwise it throws an error

Comment: Yeah, I figured you added that, but nevertheless, the code pasted above does indeed work.